# Data Fetch Error And Images are not Loading (Display) in PWA Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3.1, pwa, pwa-studio

I managed to run Venia frontend however facing the same issue. I have installed PWA venia in frontend magento 2.3.1 but images are not loading. Here are the comments to your questions. Please Help with your suggestions

**Magento version : 2.3.1**

**Operating System + version:   Ubuntu Linux 16.04**

**node.js version (node -v):    v10.15.3**

**Yarn Version: 1.15.2**

Note: Yes, Images are loading in local instance.

file / folder permissions yes

My instance is running on HTTPS

Please check the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1)First, create a virtual host for your Magento root directory. If you don't know how to set up virtual host please follow the link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Next, you need to edit the file named `makeMediaPath.js` which is placed in the path

```
pwa-studio-release/packages/venia-concept/src/util/makeMediaPath.js
```

Now change the following line

```
const mediaPath = 'http://magento23.com/pub/media/catalog';
```

In the above line please replace `magento23.com` with your virtual host

OR

2) And also you can change the `/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/.env` file with

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="http://magento23.com/magento_folder/pub"
```

In the above line please replace `magento23.com` with your virtual host

then run yarn run build

and yarn run watch:venia

Comment: not find makeMediaPath.js in pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/src/util/makeMediaPath.js

Comment: Savan Patel go with the option 2 that works fine for me

Comment: yarn run build get error ⚠ GraphQL Error (Code: 404): {"response":{"error":"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC

Comment: Have you updated you magento_root_directory name instead of magento_folder

Comment: yes updated already

Answer (score 0):

For local development in venia-concept/.env set:

IMAGE_OPTIMIZING_ORIGIN=backend

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on magento 2.4.4 
The media url printed as app.backend.test because `@magento/peregrine/lib/util7makeUrl.js` 
was fetching `store.store_code` (inexistent) instead of `store.code`

```
AVAILABLE_STORE_VIEWS.forEach(store => {
    storeSecureBaseMediaUrl[store.store_code] = store.secure_base_media_url;
});
```

**The solution** was to modify `webpack.config.js` in the project root **adding store_code** to the array and **assigning to it store.code**

1. around line 74, before global.AVAILABLE_STORE_VIEWS = availableStores

   `const availableStores2 = {}`;

   ```
   availableStores.forEach((store, index) => {
       availableStores2[index] = store;
       availableStores2[index]['store_code'] = store.code;
   });
   ```
2. and modify
    `global.AVAILABLE_STORE_VIEWS = availableStores`

   to
    `global.AVAILABLE_STORE_VIEWS = availableStores2`

   To assign it our new value containing store_code.

**Relaunch the app to see the changes.**